# Несовместимые типы операндов E0042

Tags: c++

Нужно сравнить части элементов строки с другой строкой

```
   char Q[] = "Q";
   char A[] = "A";
   int n;
   cin >> n;
   char* Mess = new char[n];
   cin >> Mess;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; n++)
   {
       if(Mess[i] == A)
   }
```

Comment: Если вы хотите сравнить каждый символ сообщения с символом 'А', то его надо определить по-другому: `char A = 'A';`. Сейчас у вас `А` - это строка, а строки нельзя сравнивать оператором `==`.

Comment: А на `cin >> Mess` никакой ошибки не было?)

Comment: С вводом проблем не было

Comment: @НикитаГусев с вводом не было ошибки пока что. Но она будет рано или поздно. В данном коде у вас выход за границу массива и неопределённое поведение. Оператор >> входного потока, при передаче в него указателя на char, будет записывать из потока в память, начиная с этого указателя, пока не встретится пробел в вводных данных.

Comment: @НикитаГусев другими словами, даже если массив кончится, программа продолжит записывать данные, перезаписывая память уже ЗА массивом. Это легко доказывается на [этом](https://godbolt.org/z/54Y8M36jj) примере.